# AJAX response time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, time, response

How I can calculate AJAX response time? I need this in script, because I get back the server timestamp, but if the request take more than 1 second I need to add 1 second to the timestamp!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the start time (just before the AJAX request is done), and then the end time when the script is complete. You can than work out the difference, and if it's greater than 60 seconds, do your thing.

```
//Before the AJAX function runs
var startTime = new Date().getTime();

//Place this code inside the success callback of your AJAX function
var endTime = new Date().getTime();
if ((endTime - startTime) > (60 * 1000)) {
    //Took longer than 60 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set two timestamps, one before the AJAX call, and once it has completed, and then diff the two.

```
var currentTime = new Date();
```

Call the above code before and after your ajax call.

In order to get the datetime diff, see Reference: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/datedifference.shtml

Comment: Yes, this will be a good method, but this javascript timestamp can be changed if user change his computer time very fast, isn't it?

Comment: They would have to do it extremely fast. Is this a likely outcome? What is the potential downfall of this action? Are you over engineering if you protect against it?

Comment: Its pretty unfeasible to think that the user will be able to change their computer clock in time. -  You could also use setInterval, as I don't think* that this relies on system time.