# How to calculate the AJAX response time safely using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, security, time

I've read many topics related to my issue, however, using `JS` technique, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728833/ajax-response-time), isn't the solution to my problem.

I'd like to calculate the `AJAX` response time. Of course, I could do it using the `Date` or `performance` object.

The problem is the user can change the `AJAX` request completely omitting the `beforeSend` and `success` parameters.

---

I don't know how to protect against it. How can I validate this? Have no idea.

Using `PHP` functions as `time()` and `microtime()` didn't help here either. It doesn't calculate it properly. For example, when I was testing it, the output in the `Chrome DevTools - Network` was about 1.5s, the output from the PHP `microtime()` was about .0083ms.

Using `time()` was absolutely terrifying because there was no difference (same second).

---

So, how can I calculate the response time of the `AJAX` request safely? It doesn't necessarily has to be `PHP` but using `client-side` languages won't help here, I guess.

Comment: Any idea, please?

Comment: why dont you calculate response time on the server side? example when request is sent to server the server should start calculate time and when request completed it should return the total time..

Comment: Did u read it fully? I've tested it, it doesn't do the same job :(

Comment: There has to be a way